# Trying to increase WP Memory Limit

Tags: installation, memory

I am trying to increase WP Memory Limit: so that I can use Fusion Builder, and other things, with WordPress but the status for the plugin is still saying I only have the limit set to 40M, even with the code lines below added to `wp-config.php`, when I want it to be at least 256M.

I am on a cloud server with WHM/Cpanel so network admin is basically me. I think I have already maxed `php.ini` so its not that.

```
  define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
  define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Please help.

Comment: you should ask your support first if you can change memory settings at all

Comment: If you're using a shared host service, there's a high probability that you're not allowed to change that setting because you're usually sharing the same resources with hundreds or even more other sites/apps.

Comment: Sorry i thought I wrote that I am self-hosting on a cloud server with whm/cpanel.

Comment: Check phpinfo to see what the memory limit is there; otherwise you might want to ask at StackOverflow for more general PHP assistance

Comment: I set the PHP mem limit to 256M. In fact I made sure nothing in php.ini was below that. Just to rules that out and yet the issue persists. It's annoying!! =)

Comment: Few answers on **[this question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-memory-limit-not-updated)** say that Apache or IIS servers also require restart after changing these settings. Did you do that?

Comment: There is a php extension, suhosin, that might interfere with changing memory size programatically.

Comment: Did you go to your WHM and check this ---> Home »Service Configuration »PHP Configuration Editor | This is the place to edit the server memory_limip for PHP on a WHM server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding to `wp-includes/default-constants.php`
You'll probably see the default values of `40M` starting around line #20, change these values. My setup is as follows:

```
// set memory limits
    if ( !defined('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT') ) {
        if ( is_multisite() ) {
            define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
        } else {
            define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never change in core!

Comment: got a better suggestion? it may be reset but at least it will work for now possibly.

Comment: Although, this is not a perfect solution it did solve my specific issue. People have to be aware that there are somewhat good reasons those limits are in the core and also that core edits will be wiped when Wordpress updates. Saying all that, I am marking this as best answer personally.